# Calling an IIFE inside of a constructor function

Tags: javascript, scope, iife

I am trying to call an IIFE from within a constructor and it doesn't seem to run when I initialize the object.  Here's my code:

```
function TitleView(el) {
  this.el = el;
  this.parent = el.parentNode;
  this.events = {
    'onclick' : function() {
      console.log('title view onclick');
    }
  };
  (function addEventHandlers() {

    for (var ev in this.events) {
      if (this.events.hasOwnProperty(ev)) {
        this.el[ev] = this.events[ev];
        console.log('abc');
      }
    }
  }());
}


var titleView = new TitleView(document.getElementById('task-title-h1'));
```

My aim here is to attach a bunch of event handlers on object initialization. If I remove the IIFE and keep the body of the code, the event handler is attached to titleView.el, but with the IIFE, it's `null`.  Why is this the case? (This is pure javascript, btw, not a framework.)

Comment: It does run, but `this` is not what you think it is. Btw, what's the reason to use an IEFE here in the first place?

Comment: The duplicate is a bit off but I think it solves your problem and answers your questions. If not, please comment.

Comment: @Bergi, Thanks for pointing me to that question.  I wanted to put this in a function and not just leave it freely sitting at the end of the constructor to make it more readable (giving it the name addEventHandlers) and the only way I could see of doing this was putting it in an IIFE.  Maybe it's excessive, though. In any case, I got it working by passing `this` into the call method of the IIFE.

Comment: You'll want to have a look at [Using Named Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) instead of comments](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15530374/1048572) then :-)