# What is the practical use of an IIFE with a name?

Tags: javascript

I'm familiar with the IIFE way to execute a function:

```
(function(){
    //stuff
}());
//immediately invoked, parsed as an expression
```

And this way in which I can assign a name to a function just by declaring it like any other object:

```
var theFunction = function(){
    //stuff
}
//can be executed with theFunction();
```

But today I saw the two combined like this:

```
var theFunction = (function(){ 
    //stuff
}());
```

What does this do, or what advantage could it provide?

Answer (score 11):

What you're showing there is not an IIFE with a name (which does exist). It's a variable that holds the *return value* of the IIFE.

---

A real IIFE with a name would be this:

```
(function myName (){
    // code here...
}());
```

The use for a name on an IIFE is two-fold:

1. For self reference. If the function wants to call itself (recursively), it can use that name (instead of `arguments.callee`, which doesn't work in strict mode).
2. It helps with debugging, as it'll show you the function's name in the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks. and what would be the advantage of an IIFE with a name in that case?

Comment: To expand, you might want an actual named IIFE if you needed to refer to the function within its own body, e.g. for recursion.

Comment: Worth pointing out, this answer doesn't actually answer the OPs question.  He wanted to know the purpose of a specific code snippet.  Its still helpful, but you might want to expand to actually explain the code he's interested in.

Comment: @ben336 - Did you read the very first sentence in the answer? The variable is used to store the return value of the IIFE. I don't think you can get any clearer than that. If what you're asking for are examples, well, there's nothing in the OP's question to indicate that they're in want for it.

Comment: Did I misunderstand? I still don't understand the usefulness of the named IIFE. I know it wasn't strictly speaking the original question, but I'd like to know. Thanks much!

Comment: @thomas you can see my examples for (very simplified) practical examples of both patterns

Comment: I was studying this, read this comment, here is what they mean by recursion 
`function demo(){
    console.log("before IIFE");
    (function myName (){
     console.log("inside IIFE");
    myName();
}());
}
demo();`

Just put it in console and see. tweek as you want.

Answer (score 5):

theFunction will be set to the return value of the IIFE.  This is generally known as the [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html)

It is a good way to allow an object to have private variables that aren't available in the global space, but that are still visible to the modules own functions, and is one of the best ways to namespace your code as a result.

for example, here is a simple private variable with getters and setters example.

It would be easy to modify this to only allow certain values to be set, limiting access to the property.

```
var module = (function(){
  var x = {};
  var private = 2;

  x.setPrivate = function(val) {
     private = val;
  }

  x.getPrivate = function() {
    return private;
  }

  return x;

}());
```

As others have pointed out, this is different from a named IIFE, which you might use if you wanted to refer to the function from within itself

```
(function foo(){
  //recursive foo call
  foo();
}()):
```

Answer (score 2):

This assigns the result of an IIFE to a variable. This can be very useful if you need a bunch of auxiliary variables to initialize the variable but don't want to pollute the namespace. Or it enables you to construct functions which have access to other auxiliary non-global "private" functions.